# Minimize space use with a randomized queue

Tags: algorithm, queue

I'm going over an algorithms online course and sometimes they pose ungraded bonus challenges for which no answer is provided. This is one of them:

> 1. You are given a positive integer k.
> 2. You will read a series of strings from the standard input (a total of `n` strings; `n` is not known to you until after you have exhausted all the strings).
> 3. You can make use of a randomized queue, which has a basic API: `size()` returns the number of elements in the queue; `enqueue(String)` adds the string into the queue; and `dequeue()` removes and returns a string from inside the queue, chosen uniformly at random.
> 4. Read all the input and at the end print `k` strings chosen uniformly at random from the set of `n` strings.
> 5. Use a randomized queue no larger than `k`.

I cannot satisfy `4` and `5` at the same time. I can get the distribution of the output to be uniform if I fill the queue with `n` strings and then make `k` calls to `dequeue()` **or** I can devise an scheme in which I only have `k` elements at most in the queue at any point, but the output is not uniform since the strings read at the beginning end up having either a greater or a smaller chance of being part of the final chosen set (depending on the algorithm I choose).

If I knew `n` in advance I could assign a random ID between 0 and `n` to each string I read, and keep a list of the `k` smallest IDs and their respective strings (e.g. `k_smallest`); if a new string is assigned a random ID smaller than any of the `k` I already have, I can decide to remove the largest element from `k_smallest` and add the new string to it. However, two problems arise: `n` is not known until after all strings have been read and the randomized queue does not allow to dequeue the largest element, only one at random.

I am very curious about the solution. How can this be solved using space proportional to `k` and not `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Key:**
You need to keep track on how many elements you have read so far.

Algo:
 l : number of `enqueue(..)`-calls so far.

1. Take the forst k elements and put them in your internal storage of size k. (e.g an array of size k). Set `l:=k`
2. For each `enqueue(..)` call after the first k, you need to decide which element to drop. If you have already enqueued l elements the probability with witch we need to keep the new element is k/l. If the random generator says keep it, you must remove a random element of the old elements. and replace it with the new one. `l:=l+1`
3. At any time you have have k evenly distributed values of the so far enqueued values (`l`) in your internal storage. At the end is `l==n`.

*P.s.

The algorithm is much more intuitive for k=1. So if you have problems getting the idea, think it through with the simplest case k=1.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand the second step. At the point of reading the string I do not know the value of `n` to set up the generator in order to decide whether I should keep it or not. Can you please add pseudo-code to your answer to make the whole process clearer?

Comment: You are right I corrected this type (of cause you use `k/l` not `k/n`)

Comment: Ah, it makes sense now! I was using this method but with a probability of `1/l`, not `k/l`. Thank you!